# Derivative use base function instead of own function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a `base` class :

base.cpp:

```
#include "base.h"

base::base() 
{
}

base::~base() {
}

void base::baseMethod(int a) 
{
    std::cout<<"base::baseMethod : "<<a<<std::endl;
}
```

base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <iostream>

class base {
public:
    base();
    base(const base& orig);
    virtual ~base();
    void baseMethod(int);

private:
};

#endif /* BASE_H */
```

And I have `derivative` class which derive from base

derivative.cpp

```
#include "derivative.h"

derivative::derivative() : base(){
}

derivative::~derivative() {
}

void derivative::baseMethod(int a)
{
    std::cout<<"derivative::baseMethod : "<<a<<std::endl;
}

void derivative::derivativeMethod(int a)
{
   baseMethod(a);
   derivative::baseMethod(a);
}
```

derivative.h

```
#ifndef DERIVATIVE_H
#define DERIVATIVE_H

#include "base.h"

class derivative : public base{
public:
    derivative();
    derivative(const derivative& orig);
    virtual ~derivative();

    void derivativeMethod(int);
    void baseMethod(int);
private:

};

#endif /* DERIVATIVE_H */
```

main.cpp

```
derivative t;
t.baseMethod(1);
t.derivativeMethod(2);
```

and output is :

```
derivative::baseMethod : 1
base::baseMethod : 2
base::baseMethod : 2
```

When I call baseMethod with derivative class object, actually I am using baseMethod of derivative class . But when I call derivetiveMethod, I am using baseMethod of base class. Why is that ? and how can I call baseMethod of derivative class ?
Thanks.

I am using `Netbeans 8.2`, `Windows 7 x64`, `g++ 5.3.0 (mingw)`

Comment: You didn't mark the `baseMethod` as `virtual`.

Comment: Not the problem but just so you know it is called derived, not derivative.  When you derive a class it becomes a derived class.

Comment: [I can't replicate it](http://ideone.com/XlJbBs).

Comment: I can't reproduce either, all calls are to the `derivative` functions as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `baseMethod` `virtual` in the base class:

`virtual void baseMethod(int);`

You *don't* need to "re-affirm" the `virtual`ness in the child classes, but some folk do that for clarity. (That also includes the destructor in the child class).

Comment: You can also "re-affirm" the fact that the derived class' function overrides a base class virtual function with `override`.  This is a bit stronger than just doing it for clarity.